# A Translation of Galois's Memoir

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, galois-theory

Is there a translation of Galois's memoir that introduced Galois Theory other than the translation by Edwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Peter M. Neumann's *The mathematical writings of Évariste Galois*, published in 2011 by the European Mathematical Society Publishing House.