# Refrence Request - Galois's Memoir

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory

Where may I find Galois's memoir on solving polynomials by radicals? Is there a PDF online?

Comment: See [Évariste Galois : External links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89variste_Galois#External_links).

Comment: I found a link [here](http://www.bibnum.education.fr/sites/default/files/galois-analysis.pdf).

Comment: For instance, http://journals.openedition.org/bibnum/616 has both a pdf of the original article and a critique essay.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516811/a-translation-of-galoiss-memoir

Answer (score 1):

The book [Galois Theory](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387909806) by Harold M. Edwards contains an English translation of Galois' memoir.

The book [The mathematical writings of Évariste Galois](http://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=137) by Peter M. Neumann "contains English translations of almost all the Galois material.  They are presented alongside a new transcription of the original French, and are enhanced by three levels of commentary."